# Could we do any email notification in azure applicationinsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

If there is any critical errors in application insights then we should send a mail notification to them.
is there any possibilities in application insights in azure 
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You'd need to define metrics and create alerts for those metrics. You'd configure whom to send the alert when creating it. Its really hard to give more exact guidelines as the question is very broad.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/alerts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-alert

Scheduled reports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-custom-reports